# AWS IoT MQTT Websocket connection from docker puppeteer problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cognito, puppeteer, aws-iot

I have a webpage that connects to AWS IoT using MQTT through a websocket with an unregistered AWS Cognito identity.

When i go to this page with a web browser (I have tested chrome,firefox,safari and mobile versions) it all works and I am connected.

I want to test the page using puppeteer through docker so i can deploy lots of machines to stress test the page.

When i use puppeteer from my local machine - it works. However, when i try to use puppeteer from inside a docker instance it doesn't.

I am using alekzonder/puppeteer:latest and a simple script that just goes to the page and waits 10 seconds. The page itself loads but the websocket connection fails:

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

Is there something i need to add to the docker image to allow websockets? or does this have something to do with the cognito identity created from a docker instance?

Comment: did you try using puppeter without docker ?

Comment: yes and it works perfectly.